# Show that the infimum of $T(v)=\|v-u\|_\infty$ is not attained

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces

Let $X=\{u\in C([0,1]):\ u(0)=0\}$ with the norm $\|u\|=\|u\|_\infty$. Let $f\in X^\star$ be defined by $$\langle f,u\rangle=\int_0^1u(x)dx $$

Let $M=\{u\in X:\ \langle f,u\rangle=0\}$ and consider the functional $T_u:M\to\mathbb{R}$ for $u\in X\setminus M$ defined by $$T_u(v)=\|v-u\|$$

Is true that the infimum of $T_u$ is not assumned for any $v\in M$? or equivalently: is there any $v\in M$ such that $$\inf_{w\in M}\|w-u\|=\|v-u\|$$

Thank you

Comment: The problem statement is quite complicated. Do you want to prove that the function $T_u$ defined by $T_u(v) = \|v - u\|$ doesn't have $0$ in the image for each $u$?

Comment: @Tunococ, I want to prove or disprove, what I have stated in the problem: If $I=\inf_{v\in M}T(v)$ then there is no $v\in M$ such that $I=T(v)$ or equivalently, we can't change $\inf$ by $\min$.

Comment: I definitely misread the problem. The correct version of your problem is definitely harder, and I tend to think the infimum cannot be attained, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What is the intuition behind your thougth @Tunococ?

Comment: I was just thinking about how an attempt to find a minimizer would be like. For example, ignoring the left-end condition and continuity, I would try to shift $u$ to have zero mean, then negate it to obtain $v$. I think this is kind of optimal in a sense, but I am still not sure. If it is, then the source of evil could be the left-end condition and continuity.

Comment: @Tunococ, suppose that $w\in M$ and $$\|w\|_\infty=\left|\int_0^1w(t)dt\right|$$ Can we conclude from it that $w=0$?

Comment: I think so. This is because $\|w\|_\infty = \int_0^1 \|w\|_\infty dt \ge \int_0^1 |w(t)| dt \ge \left|\int_0^1 w(t)dt\right|$, and the only case where the equality possible is when $w(t) = \|w\|_\infty$ for all $t$. (And we have $w(0) = 0$.)

Comment: For archive and search purposes, it would be good to add the keywords best approximation and proximinal. You are asking whether $M$ is [very non-proximinal](http://books.google.ca/books?id=yW7qlf3pRdMC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=very+non+proximinal+best+approximation&source=bl&ots=Q43F7E-wrW&sig=khcrewzTFBSVIaYNi235zIEZno0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6KLoUbLAJ_et4AOXtYCwCw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=very%20non%20proximinal%20best%20approximation&f=false) in $X$. Since it is a closed hyperplane, this is iff it is non-proximinal.

Answer (score 1):

*I believe this is correct now.*

Let $u \in X$, $U = \int_0^1u$ and $\hat v = u - U$. We first show that $\hat v$ minimizes $T_u$ in the extended domain $\widehat M = \{v \in C[0, 1]: \int_0^1 v = 0\}$. It is obvious that $\hat v \in \widehat M$.

First, observe that $T_u(\hat v) = \|\hat v - u\| = |U|$.

Then, for $w \in \widehat M$,

\begin{align*}
T_u(w) & = \|w - u\| \\
& \ge \left|\int_0^1 (w - u) \right| \\
& = \left|\int_0^1 u\right| = |U|.
\end{align*}
This shows that $\hat v$ minimizes the extended $T_u$.

Next, we show that there exists a sequence $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ in $M$ such that $T_u(v_n) \to |U|$ as $n \to \infty$. For each $n$, define $\tilde v_n \in C[0, 1]$ by $\tilde v_n(x) = x^{1/n}\hat v(x)$. Finally, define $v_n(x) = \tilde v_n(x) - 2x\int_0^1 \tilde v_n(y) dy$.

\begin{align*}
\tilde v_n(x) & = x^{1/n}\hat v_n(x) \\
& = x^{1/n}(u(x) - U) \\
v_n(x) & = x^{1/n}\hat v_n(x) - 2x\int_0^1 y^{1/n}\hat v_n(y)dy \\
& = x^{1/n}\left(u(x) - U\right) - 2x\int_0^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U)dy \\
\therefore \quad
|v_n(x) - u(x)|
& \le \left|(x^{1/n} - 1)u(x) - x^{1/n}U\right| + 2x\left|\int_0^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U)dy\right| \\
& \le \left|(x^{1/n} - 1)u(x) - x^{1/n}U\right| + 2x\left|\int_0^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U)dy\right| \\
\end{align*}
Let us now show that the sequence $I_n = \int_0^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U)dy$ converges to $0$.
Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ is given.
We know that the sequence of functions $(x^{1/n})$ converges uniformly on an interval $[x', 1]$ for any $x' > 0$, so we can pick $x' \in (0, \epsilon]$ and $N$ such that for $n > N$, $1 - x^{1/n} < \epsilon$ for $x > x'$. Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|I_n| & = &
\left|\int_0^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U) dy\right| \\
& \le & \left|\int_0^{x'} y^{1/n}(u(y) - U)dy\right| + \left|\int_{x'}^1 y^{1/n}(u(y) - U) dy\right| \\
& \le & \epsilon \|u - U\| + \left|\int_{0}^1 (y^{1/n} - 1)(u(y) - U) dy\right| + \left|\int_0^1 (u(y) - U) dy\right| \\
& \le & \epsilon \|u - U\| + \epsilon \|u - U\| = 2\epsilon \|\hat v\|.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $I_n \to 0$. Consequently, the sequence of functions $(2x|I_n|)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

We have dealt with the second part of $|v_n(x) - u(x)|$. We will show that the first part, $J_n(x) = \left|(x^{1/n} - 1)u(x) - x^{1/n}U\right|$, has a converging upper bound $|U|$. Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ is given. Same as before, we use the uniform convergence of the sequence $(x^{1/n})$ on an interval $[x', 1]$ with $x' > 0$ to choose $x' < \epsilon$ and $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $1 - x^{1/n} < \epsilon$ for $x \in [x', 1]$. Then, for $x < x'$, we have
\begin{align*}
J_n & = \left|x^{1/n}(u(x) - U) - u(x)\right| \\
& \le \left|x^{1/n}\right|\cdot\left|u(x) - U\right| + |u(x)| \\
& \le \epsilon \|u\| + \epsilon
\end{align*}and for $x \ge x'$, we have
\begin{align*}
J_n & = \left|(x^{1/n} - 1)u(x) - x^{1/n}U\right| \\
& \le \left|x^{1/n} - 1\right|\cdot|u(x)| + \left|x^{1/n}\right|\cdot|U| \\
& \le \epsilon \|u\| + |U|.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\|J_n\| \le |U| + \epsilon \|u\| + \epsilon$.

Now we can conclude that $T_u(v_n) \to |U|$ as $n \to \infty$. What is left to investigate is whether $|U|$ is attainable by any $v \in M$.
Let's assume that $v \in M$ and $T_u(v) = |U|$. Then

\begin{align*}
|U| = T_u(v) & = \|v - u\| = \int_0^1 \|v - u\| dx \\
& \ge \int_0^1 \left|v(x) - u(x)\right| dx \ge \left|\int_0^1 (v(x) - u(x)) dx\right| = |U|
\end{align*}
and all inequalities must be equalities.
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\left(\|v - u\| - |v(x) - u(x)|\right) dx & =
\int_0^1\Big|\|v - u\| - |v(x) - u(x)|\Big| dx = 0.
\end{align*}
By continuity, we must have $|v(x) - u(x)| = \|v - u\| = |U|$ for all $x$, and so $v(x) = u(x) \pm |U|$. Since $v(0) = 0$ and $u(0) = 0$, we must have $|U| = 0$, which implies $u \in M$.
Hence,

> For $u \in M - X$, the infimum of $T_u$, which is equal to $\left|\int_0^1 u\right|$, is not attainable by functions in $M$.

Comment: Since $M$ is a closed hyperplane in $X$, if some $u\in X\setminus M$ has a best approximation in $M$, then every $u$ does. So your conclusion can't be correct.

Comment: @julien I was always under the impression that the minimum cannot be attained, so I did not really expect the case $u(0) = U$ to have any significance. Now that you pointed out that point of view, I know something must be fishy, but I can't find it yet. Please help.

Comment: @julien I think I might have found it. The conclusion was wrong because I did not restrict $u$ to be in $X$. If I restrict $u(0) = 0$, then $u(0) = \int_0^1 u(x)dx$ can only happen if $u \in M$.

Comment: Sounds like a good conclusion, then. Note that it suffices to show $u(x)=x$ does not have a best approximation in $M$ to conclude that no $u\in X\setminus M$ has a best approximation. So maybe that would make your argument easier.

Comment: @julien That is definitely a lot easier path to follow. It's unfortunate that I was not trying to see the problem the right way because somehow I thought pure labor would solve this problem. Indeed it did, but the argument is nasty.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the infinity norm of $u$ is $\max_{x \in [0, 1]}u(x)$:

The answer is yes, the infimum is not obtained. I shall give a intuitive answer.

let $u\in X \\ M$. Without loss of generality, let $\int_0^1 u(x)dx$ be $\epsilon$.

Let w be another function. Under the sole restriction $\int_0^1 w(x)dx =0$, we minimize $\| w-u \|$ by having $w = u-\epsilon$. Indeed, $\|w-u \|$ would be $\epsilon$ in this case.

Now, we want $v$ to be a function with another restriction. $v(0) = 0$. However, we can make a v as close to $w$ as we desire. Therefore, the infimum of $\|v-u\|$ is still $\epsilon$, but it cannot be reached.

Comment: Could you please explain me what is $x$ in $g=\frac{\epsilon}{2}x$?

Comment: It has been made more clear.

Comment: What have you proved in your answer? Sorry, but I can't understand it.

Comment: That for any u, the infimum of T is not obtained by any v.

Comment: THere is nothing in your proof that shows this. Why $\int_0^1 u(x)dx=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$? Unless you explain better this answer: (-1).

Comment: If $v$ is the "fixed" minimizer, how do you say two lines down: "Let $v=u+g$"?

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. I have editted my answer. Please consider not using "u" as a variable for 3 different things.